# animation Flip div when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, flip

I am trying to make the divs flip whenever I click on them. I'm not sure why it doesn't work. Please help.

Here is the demo of this code. http://langbook.co/testicles-1-2-flashcards/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#flip3D{ width:240px; height:200px; margin:10px; float:left; }
#flip3D > #front{
position:absolute;
transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
background:#FC0; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: transform .5s linear 0s;}
#flip3D > #back{
position:absolute;
transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
background: #80BFFF; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: transform .5s linear 0s;}
</style>
<script>
function flip(el){
el.children[1].style.transform = "perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg)";
el.children[0].style.transform = "perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)";}
var vlib = document.getElementById('front');
vlib.addEventListener(click, flip(el));
</script>
<title>Flashcards</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="flip3D">
  <div id="back">Box - Back</div>
  <div id="front">Box - Front </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I looked at the error console, it said `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`.  Don't know how to fix this, but I hope it helps

Comment: this might works for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452477/rotate-div-text-after-clicking-on-button-using-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would move your JS to the end of the page.

It also seems like you want to be calling flip() on #flip3D, because you are trying to access it's child elements, like so:

```
var vlib = document.getElementById('flip3D');
vlib.addEventListener('click', flip(vlib));
```

To flip back, you could just keep the object's state in an attribute to know which side it's on. Also note that flip(vlib) will be called immediately; to wait for the click event, you'll need to pass a reference to the function:

```
vlib.addEventListener('click', flip);
```

Seems to work: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46u5buf8/1/)

Comment: It rotates as soon as I run it, and it does not rotate backwards when I click the bac side.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Fixed both of those; see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

ex: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_backface-visibility

easy one CSS line :

```
animation:mymove 3s infinite;
```

where *mymove* is:

```
@keyframes mymove
    {
    from {transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotateY(360deg);}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes mymove /* Firefox */
    {
    from {-moz-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Opera, Safari, Chrome */
    {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
    }

    @-ms-keyframes mymove /* Internet Explorer */
    {
    from {-ms-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
    to {-ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);}
    }
```

example:

```
div#myDIV
    {
    animation:mymove 3s infinite;/* <== HERE */
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-animation:mymove 3s infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
    /* Opera, Safari, Chrome */
    -webkit-animation:mymove 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp

Not sure if you have tried this but this my solve your problem. Using just CSS you can do the exact same thing (by the sounds of what you are trying to achieve).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few mistakes with syntax and declarations in the **JS** part.

Hope this is what you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/xrtvhvgf/2/

```
function flip(){
    if(vlib_front.style.transform){
        el.children[1].style.transform = "";
        el.children[0].style.transform = "";
    } else {
        el.children[1].style.transform = "perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg)";
        el.children[0].style.transform = "perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)";
    }
}
var vlib_front = document.getElementById('front');
var el = document.getElementById('flip3D');

el.addEventListener('click', flip);
```

Comment: Awesome! But, how can I make it flip backwards when I click the back side?

Comment: @ArielHalilajAl Just updated the JsFiddle, probably not the most optimized way but it works like a charm.