# Rotate div text after clicking on button using jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to rotate div text after clicking on button using jquery and css

If user click on `Rotate Left` button then text rotate in Left side
or
user click on `Rotate Right` button then text rotate in Right side

**Example:**

```
<div id="RotateDiv">Happy Birthday</div>

<button id="btnRotateLeft" type="button">Rotate Left</button>
<button id="btnRotateRight" type="button">Rotate Right</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ehec1gun/

```
var rotation = 0;

jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

$('#btnRotateRight').click(function() {
    rotation += 5;
    $('.rotate').rotate(rotation);
});

$('#btnRotateLeft').click(function() {
    rotation -= 5;
    $('.rotate').rotate(rotation);
});
```