# How to Rotate Text in model popup using CSS And Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to rotate div text after clicking on button using jquery and css

If user click on Rotate Left button then text rotate in Left side
or
user click on Rotate Right button then text rotate in Right side

Example:

```
<div id="RotateDiv">Happy Birthday</div>
<button id="btnRotateLeft" type="button">Rotate Left</button>
<button id="btnRotateRight" type="button">Rotate Right</button>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share what you have so far and what is not working as expected.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Rotate div text after clicking on button using jquery and css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452477/rotate-div-text-after-clicking-on-button-using-jquery-and-css)

Answer (score 0):

CSS transformations
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

You can set two classes for an element that will rotate it by different angles and add or remove those classes with jQuery.